# Error parsing XPath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am getting the following error when debugging xslt.

The xslt

```
    <xsl:variable name="is_embedded_mode" select="if ($embedded_mode_root_path_prefix != '' and $invalid_embedded_mode_request != '1') then '1' else '0'" />
```

Error message

```
[ERROR]: Syntax error in 'if ($embedded_mode_root_path_prefix != '' and $invalid_embedded_mode_request != '1') then '1' else '0''.
[ERROR]: file:default_frontend.xsl: line 62: Error parsing XPath expression 'if ($embedded_mode_root_path_prefix != '' and $invalid_embedded_mode_request != '1') then '1' else '0''.
```

Comment: **1.** Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor? -- **2.** Are the referenced variables declared and in scope?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted: - see: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWg

Comment: Show a complete XSLT stylesheet with which we can reproduce your problem. Also say _which_ XSLT 2.0 processor you are using.